# What type of exception is raised if "service.Retrieve" method doesn't find the specified entity Id in CRM?

Tags: annotations, crm

I am retrieving an annotation from CRM

```
service.Retrieve("annotation", annotationId, col);
```

What type of exception is raised if above "service.Retrieve" method doesn't find the specified "annotationId" in CRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably going to be an `OrganizationServiceFault`, see [Handle exceptions in your code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327884.aspx) for further advice.